# How to construct a map from a complicated structure by using groupBy in kotlin

Tags: java, dictionary, kotlin, group-by, collections

I'm confused about the collection in kotlin.

The structure is a little bit complicated.

```
data class Request(
    val region: Region,
    val promotions: List<Promotion>,
)


data class Promotion(
    var promotionCode: String,
    val promotionType: String,
    val coupons: List<Coupon>
) 


data class Coupon(
    val reminderType: ReminderType,
    val couponCode: String,
    val count: Int,
    val couponMultiLanguages: List<CouponDescription>
)
```

Now I want to get a map, `Map<ReminderType, List<Promotion>>`, where key `ReminderType` is the val in Coupon level, the values `List<Promotion>` is a list of promotions which is filtered by each `ReminderType` value in coupon

I get stuck here

```
val result: Map<ReminderType, List<Promotion>> = promotions.map { it.coupons.groupBy { it.reminderType } }
```

Comment: is `G2Coupon` class differnt from `Coupon` class?

Comment: @sidgate Sorry it's same. Already fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the approaches

```
val result = promotions.flatMap { p ->   //flatMap will flatten the list of list
    p.coupons.map { 
       it to p   // this creates a pair of coupon to promotion
    } 
}.groupBy(
   { it.first.reminderType } // specify reminderType as key selector
) { 
    it.second // promotion as value, groupBy adds these to list
}
```

Here we first map each coupon to promotion, and then group by coupon

Comment: Are there any way I can group by reminderType?